# Find elements before page is fully loaded using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am automating a web page using Selenium python and the automation must be very speedy.

Therefore, I'd like to find an element before page is even fully loaded. However, Selenium's **get** method seems to wait until every single images and CSS are fully loaded.

I used **driver.set_page_load_timeout(1)** method not to wait until the page load. but upon Timeout exception, Chrome browser also stops loading or rendering the page.

Is there a way to continue loading the page even after Timeout exception?

I want to rely on WebDriverWait to know the presence of the element.

```
try:
    self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(1)
    url = "http://test.com"
    self.driver.get(url)
except Exception as ex:
    pass

WebDriverWait(driver, 100, poll_frequency=0.1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID, "search_button")).click()
```

Comment: You won't able to click a button with only `presence_of_element_located` wait.

Answer (score 1):

try to use **element_to_be_clickable** if you want to click on it thus:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 100, poll_frequency=0.1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.ID, "search_button")).click()
```

Comment: The code doesn't even go to next line after .get() method before the page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

put *self.driver.get(url)* into a try, then except a TimeoutException, then code what you want to do into that, like:

```
self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(1)
url = "http://test.com"
try:
 self.driver.get(url)
except TimeoutException:
 pass
```